# Postgresql 12 Custom Hash Function

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, hashing

I have a large table that I would like to partition. The field I want to partition against is a string that contains a coded value, but appears as an integer stored as a string. The "number" is made up of 4 digits. The first two are what I want to partition against. For instance, the field value of "1298", would need to partition using the value 12. I thought this would be a great use for a hash partition with a custom hash function.

**For some reference:**
Queries are frequently made against this column in the form of `... WHERE TheField = '0123'` or `... WHERE TheField IN ('0123', '0145', '0232')`

It would be impractical to manually each value to go into each partition, so I thought using a custom hash function would be a practical solution.

**Actual Question:** How do I make this custom hash function and use it to define the partitions?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking here. Also, what you describe looks like range partitioning to me.

Comment: Can I use a range partition on a string though? I don't believe you can.

Comment: You don't have to "believe"; you can always [try and see](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=325ef4a1243165d8f75c8c047c59fc0c).

Answer (score 1):

You can partition by `substr(thefield, 1, 2)`, but there is no point in doing that unless

- you delete data by that criterion

or

- your queries use that expression

You should simply partition by hash on `thefield`, then both your queries can use partition pruning. There is no need for a custom hash function.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a true answer to the question of creating a custom hash function, the solution to my overall problem is that PostgreSQL DOES in fact support range partitions over a text field as shown by **mustaccio**.

```
CREATE TABLE dept (id CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY) PARTITION BY RANGE(id);
CREATE TABLE dept_00 PARTITION OF dept FOR VALUES FROM ('0000') TO ('0099');
CREATE TABLE dept_01 PARTITION OF dept FOR VALUES FROM ('0100') TO ('0199');
...
```